# Updating Xubuntu breaks gnumeric graph sheets in Excel file

Tags: excel, ubuntu, graph, gnumeric

Because of a HDD failure, I've had to replace it and rebuild my root file system. My data partition on my SSD stayed intact. It went from Xubuntu 14.04 to Xubuntu 16.04.

I have a spreadsheet file in Excel format so I could open it on multiple platforms; it's in my Dropbox. In that spreadsheet file I had one data sheet and seven sheets that were "full screen" graphs over that data.

After the OS update, and installing the latest gnumeric (1.12.28, don't know the old version, sorry) the data sheets that should show a graph are all empty. What's more, many menu entries become disabled when switching to those sheets, but that may be because they contain full sized graphs; I don't know, may be a red herring.

I could not find anybody with a similar issue online. The gnumeric bug list also does not mention any issues like mine. So before I start rebuilding all those graphs again, I thought I'd give good ol' StackOverflow a go. Perhaps we'll find an answer and somebody else, who's also looking for this, can find the solution here in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, please file a bug report against gnumeric. May be I can do something if you can attach the file.

Comment: I'll try to anonymise the data, which I consider sensitive, and submit an issue. (Ok, so pressing Enter is not the same as a simple newline... sorry) I just tried to open the "Excel" file in Excel and it cannot load it properly. Even the data page is not "whole"; the data is there but the formatting is missing for example. This might be due to me saving the file at some point when I still thought everything was fine...